# Dynamic cookie not working codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, cookies

I am using facebook login in codeigniter. I have followed this(http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-in-codeigniter/) tutorial.
Facebook login works as expected but cookie is not being set. If I am setting static cookie with static value then it works but if I am setting cookie with value of email of user who is using my facebook login in that case my cookie is not working.

My code Looks like this:

**Controller**

```
//Value being passed from controller: 
$data['user_email'] = $user_profile['email'];
```

**In view:**

```
if(!empty($user_email))
{
    $cookie_value = $user_email;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
    echo $_COOKIE["userlogin"]."cookie being set<br>";
}
```

`$cookie` is not printing anything which means my cookie is not working.

Comment: Are you sure `$data['user_email_log']` and then using `$user_email` is correct …?

Comment: That is just mistake but in view I am actually using $user_email_log

Comment: And you have _verified_ if that contains the expected value, at the point where you try to put it into the cookie?

Comment: yes, value is fine. I have verified this with printing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$this->input->set_cookie();
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and helper is being called in autload.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code. In your **controller** file you are passing values like this

```
//Value being passed from controller: 
$data['user_email_log'] = $user_profile['email'];
```

It means in your view you have use `$user_email_log` variable to retrieve value from controller.

You can user codeigniter cookies set functionality set cookies like this

```
 $cookie= array(
      'name'   => 'userlogin',
      'value'  => $user_email_log,
       'expire' => '86500',
  );
  $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

For more info about cookies you can check this [Link](http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/08/how-to-set-cookie-in-codeigniter.html)

Comment: What is wrong with my code in controller?
I have already tried codeigniter's method of setting cookie but that too didn't worked for me. But when I am trying to set cookie with some default value in that case it works.

Comment: i just thought you are passing wrong param from controller to  view that why i told that your code is wrong but now you commented that `That is just mistake but in view I am actually using $user_email_log`

Comment: ok, Any other help or way through which I can debug this issue?